# caxlsx gem: generated excel file displays #<Axlsx::Worksheet:0x0000559d7e487dc8>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, axlsx, caxlsx

I have a simple example, that when Excel file is generated contains `#<Axlsx::Worksheet:0x0000559d7e487dc8>`. I would like the Excel file to contain "Keys Available to be Assigned And Their Rooms".

I am using `Rails 5.2, caxlsx -v 3.1.0 and caxlsx_rails -v 0.6.2`.

Rails controller:

```
def unassigned_door_keys_n_rooms
    @qry_rslts = Reports::UnassignedDoorKeysNRooms.qry_rslts
    @csv_rslts = Reports::UnassignedDoorKeysNRooms.export_as_csv

    respond_to do |format|
      format.xml { render xlsx: 'unassigned_door_keys_n_rooms', template: 'reports/unassigned_door_keys_n_rooms.xlsx.axlsx' }
      format.csv { send_data(@csv_rslts) }
    end
end
```

Rails view unassigned_door_keys_n_rooms.xlsx.axlsx:

```
require 'axlsx'

p = Axlsx::Package.new
wb = p.workbook

s = wb.styles
header = s.add_style bg_color: 'E6E6E6', i: true, sz: 9, alignment: { horizontal: :left }

wb.add_worksheet do |sheet|
  sheet.add_row ["Keys Available to be Assigned And Their Rooms"], style: header
end
```

Comment: @Zolt's answer is correct below. Specifically, you replace your "p = Axlsx::Package.new; wb = p.workbook" line with "wb = xlsx_package.workbook"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the template file you don't need to require the gem, create the package manually or serialize it in the end - `caxlsx_rails` does it for you automatically, and you should use the helper methods provided by the gem.

See

- [the Readme about the template file](https://github.com/caxlsx/caxlsx_rails#template)
- [the current code to see all available helpers in the template](https://github.com/caxlsx/caxlsx_rails/blob/fa1ad7c1fcba92adcf499dac0520b709137b1096/lib/axlsx_rails/template_handler.rb#L21-L33)